# Trouble with creating class instance variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a little program to generate a character for a beginning c++ course.

I'm having trouble with the inventory part.

I'm using Visual Studio and when I try to set the inventory array, I get this error:

> 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'std::string *'

Googling didn't really turn up anything that worked.

Could someone take a look at the code and clue me in as to why it's failing?

Thanks

```
using namespace std;

int generateXp(int);


class Character {
private:

int xp = 0;
static const string inv[4];

public:

void setXp(int xp){
    this->xp = xp;
}

int getXp() {
    return this->xp;
}

string *getInv();

string* Character::getInv() {
string inv = { "shield", "chainmail", "helmet" };
return inv;
}

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));

Character * Gandalf = new Character;
cout << "Gandalf has " << Gandalf->getXp() << " experience points.\n";
Gandalf->setXp(generateXp(100));
cout << "Gandalf now has " << Gandalf->getXp() << " experience points.\n";
cout << "Inventory " << Gandalf->getInv() << "\n";
}

int generateXp(int base)
{
int randomNumber = 0;

randomNumber = (rand() % 5000) + 1;

return randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in the following function:

```
string* Character::getInv()
// ^^^^ The return type is std::string*
{
   string inv = { "shield", "chainmail", "helmet" };
   return inv;
   // And you are returning a std::string
}
```

Instead of:

```
string inv = { "shield", "chainmail", "helmet" };
return inv;
```

You probably meant:

```
static string inv[] = { "shield", "chainmail", "helmet" };
return inv;
```

**Update**

It will be better for you return a `std::vector`. Then you can access the contents of a `std::vector` more easily. You don't have to make assumptions about the size of the array.

```
std::vector<std::string> const& Character::getInv()
{
   static std::vector<std::string> inv = { "shield", "chainmail", "helmet" };
   return inv;
}
```

Change the usage:

```
std::vector<std::string> const& inv = Gandalf->getInv();
cout << "Inventory: \n";
for (auto const& item : inv )
{
   cout << item << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error.  But when I use cout to write out the inventory, it's just the memory pointer.  How do I output the actual contents of the array?  thanks